# Groovy Expando Serializable

Tags: java, groovy, serializable, expando

is there any way to serialize an expando subclass which can be retrieved with dynamically added properties. with the example;

```
class Sexpando extends Expando implements Serializable{
//String testProp
static final long serialVersionUID = -2056428816613381087L
String toString() {
    "an object of Sexpando - $serialVersionUID"
}
}
```

and

```
class SexpandoTest {

static main(args) {

    def s = new Sexpando()
    s.testProp = "small test string"
    println s.properties
    def file = new File('objects.dta')
    def out = file.newOutputStream()
    def oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out)
    oos.writeObject(s)

    oos.close()
    def retrieved = []

    file.eachObject { retrieved << it }

    retrieved.each { println it.properties }
}}
```

i get the output:

```
[testProp:small test string]
[:]
```

i also tried same example with original **testProp** field of Sexpando object (it is commented out  above)

Groovy's original Expando.java can be inspected from [HERE](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/util/Expando.java)

thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, it's a [long standing feature request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3812), but as Jochen says, there is an issue with what Closures should be serialized to...

Comment: hmm, allright! so i understand the problem. also i inspect the GroovyObjectSupport.java and see that the metaClass field is transient. So it can not be serialized. MOP challenging with serialization :D thank you again